# Url configuration in django always executs the same view

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to achieve the following behavior

1. http://localhost/ runs index view in my app
2. http://localhost/myview runs myview in my app

So in main urls.py I have the following setup

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^", include("myapp.urls")),
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.urls)),
]
```

and in myapp urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', "myapp.views.index"),
    url(r'myview/$', "myapp.views.myview")
]
```

but both links execute the index view and myview gets never executed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `^` to the start of your app URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', "myapp.views.index"),
    url(r'^myview/$', "myapp.views.myview")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your code to reflect below

So in main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", include("myapp.urls")),
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.urls)),
]
```

and in myapp urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', "myapp.views.index"),
    url(r'^myview/$', "myapp.views.myview")
]
```

It will work

Answer (score 1):

From [Django documentation: URL dispatcher: How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

Therefore, the order of the patterns matters. Also, your patterns as they are are too broad.

As it is, a regex `$` matches infinitely, so it first matches the index page.

Try to limit them down using a `^` before: `^$` and `^myview/$`.